# Nested time out handler is not working in Jersey AsyncResponse

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am trying to do the following for a Jersey async endpoint:

- set a timeout and a timeout handler for the response
- in case of a timeout, set a new handler and attempt to generate the response again
- finally if the response fails, return a 503

While trying to simulate this scenario, I noticed that the time out handler of the inner response is not triggered, is this a known behavior for Jersey ? Here is a code snippet explaining what I am trying to achieve.

```
 @GET
  @Produces("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
  @ManagedAsync
  public void getMyResponseAsync(@Context SecurityContext securityContext, @Suspended AsyncResponse response) throws Exception {

    response.setTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    response.setTimeoutHandler((timedoutResponse) -> {

      logger.info("request timed out, attempting to generate a new one");
      timedoutResponse.setTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
      timedoutResponse.setTimeoutHandler((finalResponse) -> {
          //this handler is never triggered even if the calculation goes beyond 1 minute
          logger.info("request timed out after a second attempt");
          finalResponse.resume(Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).build());
        }
      );
      //takes around 6mins but the handler is not trigged 
      simulateLongCalculationToTriggerTimeout();

      String value = service.getValue(value);

        timedoutResponse.resume(value);

    });

     //this triggers the first timeout
     simulateLongCalculationToTriggerTimeout();

    String value = service.getValue(value);

    response.resume(value);
  }
```

Comment: Did it work. I have a similar issue

Comment: no it did not, it's not possible using Jersey.